# BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash in SessionsController#create when I try to sign in a user? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error when I try to sign in a user, and can't figure out why. It's weird because when I run the following code I get the BCrypt Error, however when I change the find_by line (line 7) from can_email (candidate's email) to can_name (candidate's first name) I don't get the error at all, it just doesn't sign in the user presenting an "invalid password/email combination" error message on the webpage regardless if the combination is right or not. It's something to do with the password but I can't pin point it.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
 candidate = Candidate.find_by_can_email(params[:can_email])
 if candidate && candidate.authenticate(params[:password]) **Error highlights this line**
            session[:candidate_id] = candidate.id
            redirect_to candidate
 else
    flash.now[:error]="Invalid email/password combination"
    render 'new'
    end
 end

 def destroy
   if signed_in?
            session[:candidate_id] = nil
  else 
            flash[:notice] = "You need to log in first"
  end
  redirect_to login_path
 end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Having the `SessionController` i am assuming you have a route as follows

```
# This is just a sample
post 'login' => "sessions#create" # gives login_path
```

Since there will be no session model i assume you have the form as follows

```
form_for(:session, url: login_path)
```

Now if you are collecting eg can_email and password you get

```
{session: {password: 'foo', can_email: 'foo@bar.com'}}
```

Accessing `params[:session]` returns the hash containing email and passowrd
So i think you should obtain them as follows

```
def create
  candidate = Candidate.find_by(can_email: params[:session][:can_email])
  if candidate && candidate.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    # login the user
  else
    # whatever
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, but in my case it was the result of myself having changed the `encrypted_password` value of my user in the database a while back and then forgetting about it.

This was easily fixed just by updating the password :)